# how to install npm sanitize

Tags: node.js, npm, sanitize

I'm learning about node.js and trying to install npm sanitize but it doesn't work.
install codes and errors are below

```
C:\Users\Stephen Lee\Desktop\nodejs>npm install -S sanitize-html
npm WARN nodejs@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN nodejs@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Stephen Lee\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\domutils
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Stephen Lee\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\domutils' -> 'C:\Users\Stephen Lee\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\.domutils.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Stephen Lee\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-28T10_13_00_967Z-debug.log
```

although I did `npm init` to create json file but it didn't work
please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: what happens when you run `npm list`?

Comment: extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Stephen Lee\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\dom-serializer\package.json         this is what i got

Comment: What about `npm -v` and `node -v`? I suspect an installation problem

Comment: no error, just version showed up.